# virtualbox connecting server and client

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-server-2012

so I want to finally set up my home virtual environment.. basically just a Windows server machine and a client Windows 7. I tried to do it couple of times already, but after setting up the server I failed to connect the two machines.

Now I have a clean install of both, the server doesn't have any DNS, DHCP - anything. Before I install all of this, I want to make sure I have it right - because as I mentioned, I failed a couple of times before and I need to get it right this time.

I get my default internet connection from a home router into my notebook, so both the machines have exactly the same ip config.

[image: IP Configuration]

[image: IP Configuration]

Both have a dual network cards, one to external to receive WAN connection and one internal, to communicate between each other.

[image: VM Config]

[image: VM Config]

Now my question is - when installing the server, do I need to enter any specific IPs (for the domain for example) and configuration? In my previous attempts, I just entered randomly some stuff...the server alone worked, but I wasn't able to ping it nor connect to it via the client.

Comment: You really don't need a second network adapter if both machines are using NAT on the first.  They'll be on the same private network behind the NAT.

Comment: I was thinking that the NAT will receive the WAN connection only. Maybe for the client PC it's not necessary to have both, you are right. But also in real life servers - you have to have 2 NICs.